# Hypergeometric Distribution Problem: Acceptance sampling

Tags: probability

A bicycle manufacturing company supplies cheap bicycle in a lot of 50,An agent before asking the lot , test a random sample of 10 bicycles and if all are good, he accept a lot otherwise he refuse it . what is the probability that he will accept a lot containing 5 defective bicycles. what is the probability that he will reject a lot containing only two defective bicycles?

Comment: Do you have any more information on how frequently this company supplies defects? If not, the probability will depend on that factor.

Comment: Since the agent is drawing bikes without replacement, this is a hypergeometric experiment (as opposed to a binomial experiment where the draws are with replacement).

Comment: this question cannot be answered without some prior probability of defect

Comment: The answer can be obtained without prior probability of defect. We are told that the lot contains 5 defective bicycles out of 50. That is all we need. This is a hypergeometric experiment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution

Comment: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Ty8rDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA223&dq=a+bicycle+manufacturing+company+supplies+cheap+bicycle+in+a+lot+of+50&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8lPzJmvnQAhWLP48KHebbClgQ6AEIMzAA#v=onepage&q=a%20bicycle%20manufacturing%20company%20supplies%20cheap%20bicycle%20in%20a%20lot%20of%2050&f=false

Comment: Kindly check this link... this question is correct

Comment: @MichaelR you're right. I was to busy looking for the word "probability = #"  that i skimmed right over that. Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the draws are not independent, this is not a binomial experiment. Rather, it is a hypergeometric experiment. Recall the probability mass function of a hypergeometric distribution:

$$ f(k) = \frac{\binom{S}{k} \times \binom{N-S}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{S}} $$

where $ N $ is the total number of objects in your sample, $ S $ is the number of objects in your sample that correspond to a "success," and $ n $ is the number of draws that you make from your sample.

In this context, we can consider a defective bike to be a "success."

For the first part of your question, this means that we have: $ N = 50 $, $ S = 5 $, and $ n = 10 $. You want to find $ f(k=0) $.

For the second part of your question, we want to find the probability that a lot containing only 2 defective bikes is rejected. In that case, we have: $ N = 50 $, $ S = 2 $, and $ n = 10 $. We want to find $ f(k \geq 1) = 1 - f(k < 1) = 1 - f(k=0).$

Comment: Thank you very much..but hypergeometric distribution is not taught to us......

Comment: can we do it using binomial, if yes how?

Comment: @neelam No. Since the samples are drawn without replacement, you can't use the binomial distribution.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @MichaelR these are basic problems involving the hypergeometric
distribution. You will need to evaluate some 'binomial coefficients' (such as ${50 \choose 10}$) in order to get the answers on a simple calculator.

Here are some answers I got using R statistical software, so you can check
your answers when you get them.

Probability no bad bikes in a sample of 10 from a lot with 5 bad and 45 good bikes.

```
dhyper(0, 5, 45, 10)
## 0.3105628
```

Probability at least one bad bike in a sample of 10 from a lot with 2 bad and 48 good bikes.

```
1 - dhyper(0, 2, 48, 10)
## 0.3632653
```

Comment: Thank you very much..but hypergeometric distribution is not taught to us....but the answers are correct

Comment: My guess is that you have covered some combinatorial methods that allow you to get the answer, without using the terminology 'hypergeometric'. Ordinarily, on this site, we expect you to show what you tried and where you got stuck. I doubt anyone is going to give you a 'screen-shot ready' answer to a hwk problem. When you have what you need from this post, please accept one of the answers, so we will know to stop posting Answers and making Comments.

Comment: can we do it using binomial, if yes how?

Comment: No. Binomial is for sampling with replacement, or sampling from an essentially infinite population. Here the population has 50 elements, and it makes no sense to sample with replacement (i.e. potentially to test the same bike more than once). This is an introductory example of what quality management engineers call 'acceptance sampling', a term you can google with lots of hits.